# Можно ли опустить тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными существительными?

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли в предложении такого типа:

Как первый порыв (-) есть порыв инстинктивный, так и ....

Необходимо ли здесь тире или его можно опустить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными существительными, вместо глагола-связки "есть", "является". В Вашем же предложении этот глагол имеется, поэтому тире не нужно